# Github Copilot Stop Working, Error parsing extraData: service unavailable

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I was using [github copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) up until recently (probably early Sept 2021), and suddenly notices that copilot stop showing suggestions.

I inspected the logs in the VSCode and it shows similar output every time

```
[INFO] [ghostText] [2021-09-09T14:23:50.510Z] Breaking, no choices
[INFO] [default] [2021-09-09T14:23:58.685Z] [fetchCompletions] engine https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex
[INFO] [ghostText] [2021-09-09T14:23:58.876Z] Breaking, no choices
[INFO] [default] [2021-09-09T14:23:58.989Z] [fetchCompletions] engine https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex
[INFO] [default] [2021-09-09T14:23:59.313Z] request.response: [https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex/completions] took 323 ms
[ERROR] [streamChoices] [2021-09-09T14:23:59.314Z] Error parsing extraData: service unavailable
```

I tried to search for this issue (google, StackOverflow, GitHub issues, etc.), and unfortunately still no answer to this. Was wondering if anyone experiencing a similar issue and maybe have found the solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I managed to solve this with the classic sign-out-sign-in solution.

1. Signing out from your GitHub account in VSCode
2. Close VSCode
3. Open VSCode, copilot will prompt you to sign in to GitHub to use the feature.
4. Voila, copilot working again

Answer (score 0):

Go to **extensions** tab then search for `copilot`, when it appears select it and update it to the new suggested version then reload the VSCode editor, when you reload copilot will prompt you to accept the telemetry terms, click `Agree` to continue using this extension :

[image]